# Как сделать чтобы уникальный номер id,url,media показывался в тулзах в aplication Как на примере скриншота

Tags: javascript, localstorage

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const cardData = {
      id: // ?????,

      media: card.parentNode.childNodes[1].attributes.src,

      section: card.children[2].innerText, //categories

      title: card.childNodes[3].children[0].innerText, //card__title

      abstract: card.childNodes[3].children[0].children[1].innerText, //card__description

      published_date: card.childNodes[3].children[1].children[0].innerText, //card__date

      url: card.childNodes[3].children[1].children[0],

      read: true, //Boolean
    };
```

```
            <div class="card" id-data="${id}" >
                <div class="wrap__img">
                  <img class="card__img is-reading" src="${src}" alt="${source}" />
                  <button type="button" class="card__favorite">
                    Add to favorite
                    <svg class="icon-heart unchecked">
                      <use class="icon" href="/icons.adfc4680.svg#empty-heart"></use>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="icon-heart is-hidden-btn">
                      <use class="icon" href="/icons.adfc4680.svg#fill-heart"></use>
                    </svg>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="news__card">
                <div class="news__card--info">
                <h2 class="card__title">${title.substr(0, 55)}</h2>
                <p class="card__description">${
                  abstract.substr(0, 100) + '...'
                }</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card__footer">
                  <span class="card__date">${published_date}</span>
                  <a class="card__ref"  target="_blank"
                  rel="noreferrer noopener">Read more</a>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="categories">${section}</div>
                <div class="read visually-hidden">Have read</div>
```

Comment: Можно как то подробнее, что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Я хочу сделать так чтобы в local storage выводилось уникальное айди картинки как на фото что я скинул let localStorageData = {
  options: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cardsInfo'))
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cardsInfo'))
    : [],
};
console.log('localStorageData', localStorageData.options);

export function addNewsToLocalStorage(event) {
  if (event.target.className === 'card__ref') {
    const card = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement; это то что над кодом который я скинул

Comment: Все равно не понятно. Выводились куда? В локолСтораже это уже лежит. Судя по коду, в консоль вы тоже выводите. Вывод данных в консоль нестандартизирована, поэтому каждый браузер будет это делать по своему.

Comment: Я скрин кинул со своего ноута с другой страницу мне же нужно сделать тоже самое

Comment: Положите свои данные в localStorage и они будут лежать там, где указано...

Answer (score 0):

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgwGi.jpg

```
это то что у меня сейчас а на первом скрине как должно быть
```

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос и добавьте это туда

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Как сделать так чтобы сохраненое в local storage не дублировалось как на скрине
```

```
import axios from 'axios';
import NewsApiService from '../api/api-news';
import fetchPopularNews from '../gallery';

const gallery = document.querySelector('.news__gallery');
console.log(gallery);

gallery.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const viewedRead =
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(getPopularCardData())) || '[]';
  console.log(viewedRead);
  if (e.target.nodeName !== 'A') {
    return;
  }
});

async function getPopularCardData() {
  let response = await axios.get(
    'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/emailed/7.json?api-key=ctrAXxxlZTZKIuOVxETyJyELWuuMaa5A'
  );
  console.log(response);
  const data = response.data.results;
  saveData(data);
}

const cardSave = [];
const card = {};

function saveData(data) {
  data.map(
    ({ media, source, title, abstract, published_date, url, section, id }) => {
      let src = media.length
        ? media.map(media => media['media-metadata'][2].url)
        : 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRvFBa3G11OUBYADP7ouSBgwiiRzSYorF4dfg&usqp=CAU';

      card['id'] = `${id}`;
      card['url'] = `${url}`;
      card['source'] = `${source}`;
      card['title'] = `${title}`;
      card['section'] = `${section}`;
      card['abstract'] = `${abstract}`;
      card['published_date'] = `${published_date}`;
      card['src'] = `${src}`;

      cardSave.push(card);
      console.log(card);
      localStorage.setItem(`news`, JSON.stringify(cardSave));
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Я не знаю как написать яснее , просто хотелось чтобы кто-то обяснил мне

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).